How can I install specific version of imap for php on Linux?
Whenever I try to install imap for PHP 8.2 with:
sudo apt-get install php8.2-imap

In response I get:
Could not find any package by glob 'php8.2-imap'

I also tried installing it with:
sudo apt-get install php-imap

But then it fetches version for php 7.2 and of course it's not what I want. I do use ppa ondrej repository and I do work on Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

Please share more details. Linux Mint 19 is pretty outdated and out of support since April 2023. The repositories maintained by Ondrej Sury don't provide packages for out of support operating systems

I think I can close this question, since there is no longer need for a solution to my problem. Lately I got new PC and after fresh installation with new system and updated repositories (Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon) it found this repository without a problem.
My bet is that I had non-updated repositories... But as I stated, it's just a guess.
In any case folks, remember to keep your repos and system updated:
sudo apt-get update

Cheers.

It seems like the package php8.2-imap is not available in the repository you're currently using. Since you're using the ondrej repository, you might want to check if there's a specific package for PHP 8.2 IMAP extension in that repository.
You can search for available PHP packages in the ondrej repository using the apt-cache search command. Try running:
apt-cache search php8.2-imap

I guess there are none since there is no output.

A way around this is to upgrade from PHP version 7.2 to PHP version 8.2
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-php-on-ubuntu/

The thing is I do have multiple versions of PHP installed already, including 8.1 and 8.2.
